# JQuery Remove Stylesheet and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, get

I am loading in content via AJAX. In the process I get a new JS file and stylesheet:

```
$.getScript('apps/' + appl + '/js/html5.js', function(){
    $('head').append( $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').attr('href', 'apps/' + appl + '/css/webkit.css'));
});
```

How would I remove the stylesheet and JS file with Jquery.

Comment: You should consider using IDs for stylesheets so you can easily remove it with $("link#YOUR_ID").remove();

Answer (score 0):

if u update href to your link element it will update css files, making it empty will remove css, and same for js file remove the link:

try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css" type="text/css">
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("link[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "newFile.css"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("link[href=XXXXXXX]").remove();
```